# c++ list splicing help

Tags: c++, list, iterator, splice

I am trying to splice this list but I am getting an error saying no matching function when I call the splice. All my #includes are correct as far as I know.

Error is coming from every line that calls temp.

```
void DeckOps::encrypt(int msize, list<int> *L){

    int jokeA = 27;
    int jokeB = 28;
    string keystream;

    list<int>::iterator a = std::find(L->begin(), L->end(), jokeA);
    list<int>::iterator new_position = a;
    for(int i=0; i < 1 && new_position != L->begin(); i++)
        new_position--;

    L->insert(new_position, 1, *a);

    L->erase(b);

    list<int>::iterator aa = L->begin();
    int sec;
    for(; aa != L->end(); aa++){
        if(*aa == jokeA || *aa == jokeB)
            break;  //aa is at 1st inlist either 27 or 28                                                                                                    
    }
    if(*aa == jokeA){
        sec = jokeA;
    } else {
        sec = jokeB;
    }
    list<int>::iterator bb = std::find(L->begin(), L->end(), sec);   

    // everything works up to this point it seems
    list<int> temp;
    temp.splice(temp.end(), L, aa, bb);
    temp.splice(temp.end(), L, bb);
    temp.splice(temp.end(), L, begin(), aa);
    L->splice(L->end(), L, aa);
    L->splice(L->end(), temp);

    //testing                                                                                                                                          
    std::copy(L->begin(), L->end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding your #include(s) in the code, if you are not 100% sure of them.

Comment: error is occurring when I call anything on temp, any function I know to me included in list

Answer (score 4):

L is a pointer, you need to dereference it.

```
temp.splice(temp.end(), *L, aa, bb);
```

Or you can of course pass it in by reference instead, up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The splice function has prototypes declared as:

```
void splice ( iterator position, list<T,Allocator>& x );
void splice ( iterator position, list<T,Allocator>& x, iterator i );
void splice ( iterator position, list<T,Allocator>& x, iterator first, iterator last );
```

The second parameter `L` you are passing to the functions is declared as a pointer:

```
list<int> *L
```

This results in a no matching function error because there is no splice function which takes second parameter as an pointer. You will have to dereference your pointer `L` to match the function prototype of `splice`.

```
temp.splice(temp.end(), *L, aa, bb);
temp.splice(temp.end(), *L, bb);
temp.splice(temp.end(), *L, begin(), aa);
```